# Where is the derby.jar file within my Java 11 installation on Mac?

Tags: java, derby

I just read [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html), that the Java DB (respectively Derby) is shipped with the JDK.

Where is the `derby.jar` within the Java installation on my Mac?

The terminal command

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

prints

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and

```
ls -halt /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home

drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel   320B  6 Okt 14:29 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160B  6 Okt 14:29 ..
-r--r--r--   1 root  wheel   160B  6 Okt 14:29 README.html
drwxr-xr-x  34 root  wheel   1,1K  6 Okt 14:29 bin
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel   224B  6 Okt 14:29 conf
drwxr-xr-x   9 root  wheel   288B  6 Okt 14:29 include
drwxr-xr-x  72 root  wheel   2,3K  6 Okt 14:29 jmods
drwxr-xr-x  72 root  wheel   2,3K  6 Okt 14:29 legal
drwxr-xr-x  57 root  wheel   1,8K  6 Okt 14:29 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   1,2K  6 Okt 14:29 release
```

The only `jar` file within the Home folder I can find is the following:

```
find . -name '*.jar'
./lib/jrt-fs.jar
```

Thank you for your help!

P.S.:

```
java -version
```

prints

```
java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 6):

As of JDK 9, Derby is [no longer included](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8080959) in the JDK. From the [migration guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-B86166DA-6307-4E2F-B410-863EE5D2047F):

> JavaDB, which was a rebranding of Apache Derby, isn’t included in JDK 9.
>
> JavaDB was bundled with JDK 7 and JDK 8. It was found in the db directory of the JDK installation directory.
>
> You can download and install Apache Derby from [Apache Derby Downloads](https://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html).