# Where can I find derby.jar in JDK 8?

Tags: java, ubuntu, jdbc, java-8

I am reading about JDBC in OCP Java book, and in this book, it explains about JavaDB and before running my code, I need to add derby.jar file to my classpath.

```
java −cp "/my/jdk/home/db/lib/derby.jar:." SetupDerbyDatabase
```

**OS:** Ubuntu 19.04

**Java version:** 8

Comment: derby is not part of the JDK. I would recommend using a build tool like [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [gradle](https://gradle.org/) to manage dependencies like derby.

Comment: You can download from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/derby/derby/10.15.1.3/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911999/where-is-the-derby-jar-file-within-my-java-11-installation-on-mac Note that Derby (JavaDB) was only ever included in the Oracle JDK distributions, it wasn't part of JDK distributions of other vendors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JDK is being slimmed down and derby is no longer part of the distribution.

You must download the jar manually and then use the path to the downloaded jar instead of the one you use today.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using netbeans then try this path
C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\javadb\lib

you'll found derby client name jarfile for jdbc connection

Answer (score -2):

You can download the required version from https://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html and then save it under this location. /my/jdk/home/db/lib/

Comment: Dependencies like Derby don't belong in your JDK installation folder.